# Can determiners precede pronouns?

Tags: nouns, pronouns, determiners

Generally, determiners are defined as preceding nouns, but can they also precede pronouns? For example, the word "least" can take a number of forms including adverb, adjective, determiner, AND pronoun, as in "that's the least of my problems" or "he earns the least". These examples are used to illustrate the usage of "least" as a pronoun. But isn't it actually a "noun" in these contexts? Then it would make sense for a determiner to precede it.

Comment: You should explain why you think *least* can ever be a determiner. Or that it can somehow elsewhere be a pronoun. You have illustrated no such examples as of yet.

Comment: Here is an example: "He generally takes the path of least resistance." - unless you prefer to classify that use as an adjective. However, that is somewhat not the point of my question. Even if you dismiss that "least" can be a determiner (though several dictionaries do), my question has to do with whether in my examples whether it is a noun or pronoun. There seems to be other words like this also, like "one", which seems to be classified as a pronoun, which makes sense for "one needs to know", but what about "the one I told you about".

Comment: Just an added note...your last sentence seems to imply that my examples of "least" are not pronoun uses. If so, then would you consider those uses as "nouns"?

Comment: No, of course your examples are not nouns. They’re adjectives inflected into the superlative degree. You can tell it’s an adjective because you can modify it with *very*, something you can do only to adjectives and adverbs, never to nouns or verbs. Thus it is not a noun. QED.

Comment: @tchrist you’re sure? Because you’re the very person I’d expect to know about such things.

Comment: @ThePhoton "very adjective
verier; veriest
Definition of very (Entry 2 of 2)
1a: EXACT, PRECISE
the very heart of the city" https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/very

Comment: Ahhhh...I was familiar with superlative adjective usage but was only thinking of it where it accompanies a noun. I see now that superlative adjectives are part of the category of nominal adjectives (aka adjectival nouns) https://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/adjectiv/nominal.htm

Comment: @ThePhoton I meant as an adverbial intensifier. The one with the noun is an adjective. It's not the one I was talking about.

Comment: &tchrist So in the phrase “the very least”, which *very* are we using?

Comment: "Least" is never a pronoun. It is a determinative in "Ed made the least mistakes"; an adverb in "This one is the least expensive" and an adjective in your example "That's the least of my problems", where it is functioning as a modifier in a fused-head noun phrase meaning "That's the lesser problem of some set of problems"

Comment: @BillJ, I agree in your examples there is no ambiguity of the role of "least". But in my examples, I forgot that the adjectival superlative form can function as a noun even without that implied noun being present. Additionally, I was confused by the fact that the Oxford Learner's Dictionary AND the Macmillan Dictionary (both available online) offer "least" as a pronoun (unless I am confused about their notation).

Comment: That still leaves open the question of whether "least" can also be a determiner (knowing that there is some debate about whether determiners are a different class than adjectives). For example, in the phrase, "she took the path of least resistance" is "least" just functioning as an adjective or (as some sources suggest) it is a determiner.

Comment: At least you got some discussion.

Comment: @tangosquared But it doesn't function as a noun -- this is where you're going wrong.In both your examples, "least" is an adjective, not a noun. Where dictionaries talk of it being a pronoun, it is actually an adjective in a fused-head construction.

Comment: I see that I have wandered into what appears to be a grammarians' hornet's nest. :-) Upon some additional research, it appears what you call word forms whose type (or combination of types) may be one thing, but act in the role of others have a variety of interpretations. While I am certain the following link (https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2016/08/number.html) may be challenged in terms of its authority, I found it helpful to understand why there may be a disparity in terms of classifications here.